# How to integrate MailChimp in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Using powershell, I want to create a mail list and add subscribed users to that list through MailChimp API v 3. I think I would read an SQL database of users then do a HTTP Post call to the mailchimp API for creating a list and batch posting the subscribed users.

Does any one have sample code or a simple tutorial?

I was only able to find old versions mailchimp v2/1 code samples:
http://poshcode.org/3479
http://poshcode.org/3351

Thanks.